# Position of a Node after addChild

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I have an `SKSpriteNode` like a light gray square in the view, and I want to put a label inside it... I do this way:

```
let puntosCubo = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.lightGrayColor(), size: CGSize(width: gameoverTitle.frame.width, height: gameoverTitle.frame.height*4))
puntosCubo.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)-100, y:y2)
```

I put a SKLabelNode inside `puntosCubo`  this way:

```
let puntosCuboTitle1 = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Apple SD Gothic Neo")
    puntosCuboTitle1.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    puntosCuboTitle1.fontSize = 20
    puntosCuboTitle1.text = "Score"
    puntosCubo.addChild(puntosCuboTitle1)
    puntosCuboTitle1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: puntosCubo.position.y)
```

But the result is that the position of the `SKLabelNode` is not inside `puntosCubo`.  I think i am using the position of `puntosCubo` on a wrong way...

Any ideas/help.  Thanks.

Comment: Show us where your node is. Is it completely outside of the node or at the edge?

Comment: The position of puntosCubo  is outside of the view, because I want it to moveTo the center of the view with a SKAction ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of

```
puntosCubo.addChild(puntosCuboTitle1)
```

the position of the label puntosCuboTitle1 is ***relative*** to the postion of its parent (puntosCubo)

```
puntosCuboTitle1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

makes the position of the puntosCuboTitle1 in the middle of its parent puntosCubo

Comment: Ok. The most important was that the position of puntosCuboTitle1 is the MIDDLE of its parent ... thanks.